# Is it bad to use static ADO.NET function for a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Below is a model class for my ASP.NET MVC Project.
I am concerned about the below code. Is it a good idea to use static function to return a list for a website when multiple users will be using it?
Will there be a conflict when users are accessing the data through a static function?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BusinessLogic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace Exam.Models
{
    public class QuestionGroups
    {
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
        public string PreviewText { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
        public int ExamID { get; set; }
        public string ExamName { get; set; }

        public static List<QuestionGroups> GetQuestionGroupList ()
        {
            List<QuestionGroups> questionGroupList = new List<QuestionGroups>(); 
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExamConstr"].ConnectionString; 
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT A.*, B.ExamName FROM QuestionGroups A INNER JOIN Exams B ON A.ExamID = B.ExamID";
            DataLayer dl = new DataLayer(constr);
            DataTable tableData =  dl.GetRows(sqlQuery, null);
            foreach(DataRow singleRow in tableData.Rows)
            {
                QuestionGroups qgroup = new QuestionGroups();
                qgroup.GroupID = Convert.ToInt32(singleRow["GroupID"]) ;
                qgroup.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(singleRow["CreatedDate"]);
                qgroup.GroupTitle = singleRow["GroupTitle"].ToString();
                qgroup.PreviewText = singleRow["PreviewText"].ToString();
                qgroup.Keywords = singleRow["Keywords"].ToString();
                qgroup.ExamID = Convert.ToInt32(singleRow["ExamID"]);
                qgroup.ExamName = singleRow["ExamName"].ToString();
                questionGroupList.Add(qgroup);
            }
            return questionGroupList;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code of my DataLayer class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public class DataLayer
    {
        string connectionString = ""; 
        public DataLayer(string constr)
        {
            connectionString = constr;
        }

        public DataTable GetRows(string sqlQuery, SqlParameter[] sqlParam)
        {
            DataTable tableData = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParam);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dread = com.ExecuteReader();
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Load(dread);
                    dread.Close();
                }
            }
            return tableData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this instance, the static method is using instance level variables, meaning you should be ok. Better if it wasn't `static` (e.g., for unit testing) but the code looks ok

Comment: I would be more concerned about having SQL statements and other ADO.NET stuff in my model. Keep that in your data layer.

Comment: @PalleDue If I move sql statements to my DataLayer. I may need multiple functions for each model classes I have.

Comment: @YesudassMoses: Yes, but your models would become much smaller and cleaner. You would have better separation of concerns.

Comment: @PalleDue Thank you.
 I am making a Repository class for the ado.net functions. Is that okay?

Comment: Static methods are not possible to use in conjunction with dependency injection (only with service location). If you ever want to upgrade your application to AspNetCore in the future, you should definitely refrain from using static methods for features that have (or may eventually need) dependencies (such as DbContext/db connections). But then, as others have pointed out the fact that your method is static is less worrying than the fact that you have inline SQL statements and a lack of separation of concerns. This app would probably need to be rewritten instead of upgraded, anyway.

Comment: @YesudassMoses: Yes, a repository class wrapping the ADO.net stuff would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static *functions* are fine - they just let you call the function without an instance of the containing class.

Static *data* can be very bad for ASP.NET sites since static data will be shared across all sessions.

That said, since you're not using any static data, there is no reason for the method to be `static`. I would say you need to separate the "get data" function from the data class itself into a "repository" class or the like, and use non-static methods.

Comment: Static data can be fine if it's read only, and never changed.  For example, a list of states, which might be shown as options for picking a state or used for validating if an entered value is a valid state, seems like a reasonable example.

Comment: Thanks for the repository class idea.

Comment: As an example of static/shared data, consider ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExamConstr"] from the OP's code. I would want to check that this is thread safe for reads.

Comment: Static data -- We luvs us sum static fields that when our Azure Configuration changes wheeze can re-right dem wid new valuze and not has to restarts our service.  Absolutes are always wrong.  Static data has its place.